# AcceptEx returns 1022 (WSAEINVAL)... What did I do wrong?

Tags: c++, winsock, overlapped-io

I am trying to code a small test-server for completion ports.
But when I try to call AcceptEx... it always returns WSAEINVAL as the winsock error code...
I don´t really get what was my mistake

http://codepad.org/NEXG3Ssh <- code on codepad

and

```
StartWinsock();
 cout << "Winsock initiated\n";
 //Get the number of processors
 DWORD ulProcessors = GetNumberOfProcessors();
 cout << "Number of Processors/Threads, that will be used: " << ulProcessors << endl;
 //Create an completion port
 hCompletionPort = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, ulProcessors);
 if(hCompletionPort == NULL)
  ErrorAbort("Could not create completion port");
 cout << "Completion Port created\n";

 //Create threads
 CreateThreads(ulProcessors);
 cout << "Threads created\n";

 //Create socket
 AcceptorSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
 addrinfo *final, hints;
 memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
 hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
 hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
 if(getaddrinfo(NULL,"12345", &hints, &final))
  ErrorAbort("Could not retrieve address information");
 if(bind(AcceptorSock,final->ai_addr, final->ai_addrlen))
  ErrorAbort("Could not bind socket");
 freeaddrinfo(final);
 cout << "Acceptor socket created and bound\nStarting to listen on the acceptor socket\n";
 if(listen(AcceptorSock, 2))
  ErrorAbort("Can´t listen on the socket");

 //Add acceptor socket file handle to be observed by the completion port
 if(CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE)AcceptorSock, hCompletionPort, NEW_CONNECTION, 0) != hCompletionPort)
  ErrorAbort("A new completion port has been created instead of using the existing one");
 cout << "Acceptor socket associated with the completion port\n";

 ResumeThreads(2);
 char lpOutputBuf[1024];
 int outBufLen = 1024;
 DWORD dwBytes;
 OVERLAPPED over;
 SOCKET newSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);


 while(true)
 {
  memset(&over, 0, sizeof(over));
  if(AcceptEx(AcceptorSock, newSock, lpOutputBuf, outBufLen - ((sizeof(sockaddr_in) + 16) * 2), sizeof(sockaddr_in)+16, sizeof(sockaddr_in)+16, &dwBytes, &over) == FALSE)
  {
   int x = WSAGetLastError();
   if( x != WSA_IO_PENDING)
    ErrorAbort("Could not acceptex a new connection");
  }
 }
```

Comment: You really don't want that while(true) loop there... And if you do want to post more that one async accept then you need to create a 'newSock' for each call to AcceptEx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te problem in your code is this:

```
while(true)
{
  memset(&over, 0, sizeof(over));
  if(AcceptEx(AcceptorSock, newSock, lpOutputBuf, outBufLen - ((sizeof(sockaddr_in) + 16) * 2), sizeof(sockaddr_in)+16, sizeof(sockaddr_in)+16, &dwBytes, &over) == FALSE)
  {
    int x = WSAGetLastError();
    if( x != WSA_IO_PENDING)
    ErrorAbort("Could not acceptex a new connection");
  }
}
```

The second parameter of the AcceptEx Function (in this case newSock) must be a unconnected and unbound socket, then when a new connection arrives the newSock parameter will be an invalid parameter (because now is connected), to avoid this a New Socket Handle must be created, but the loop must wait until the new connection arrives, to do this a WSAEVENT must be use.  The first the function WSAEventSelect must be used to associate the FD_ACCEPT Network event with the WSAEVENT, this mus be done before the creation of the AcceptThread:

```
g_ev = WSACreateEvent();
if (WSA_INVALID_EVENT == g_ev)
  ErrorAbort("Error occurred while WSACreateEvent()";
if (SOCKET_ERROR == WSAEventSelect(AcceptorSock, g_ev, FD_ACCEPT))
{
  WSACloseEvent(g_ev);
  ErrorAbort("Error occurred while WSAEventSelect().");
}
```

The AcceptThread Then Call The AcceptEx Function and Wait for a New Connection, when a new connection arrives the newSock is Added to the Completion port and a new Socket is created, this thread have only the elements required to accept connections:

```
DWORD WINAPI AcceptThread(LPVOID lParam)
{
  SOCKET AcceptorSock = (SOCKET)lParam, new;
  SOCKET newSock; 
  OVERLAPPED over;    
  DWORD wr;

  memset(&over, 0, sizeof(over));
  do
  {
    newSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(AcceptEx(AcceptorSock, newSock, lpOutputBuf, outBufLen - ((sizeof(sockaddr_in) + 16) * 2), sizeof(sockaddr_in)+16, sizeof(sockaddr_in)+16, &dwBytes, &over) == FALSE)
    {
      int x = WSAGetLastError();
      if (x != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
      {
        cout << "Could not acceptex a new connection" << endl;
        return 1;
      }
      else
      {
        if (WSA_WAIT_TIMEOUT != (wr = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1,  &g_ev, FALSE, INFINITE, FALSE)))
        {
          WSAEnumNetworkEvents(AcceptorSock, g_ev, &WSAEvents);
          if ((WSAEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_ACCEPT) &&  (0 == WSAEvents.iErrorCode[FD_ACCEPT_BIT]))
          {
            if (CreateIoCompletionPort(newSock, hCompletionPort, 0, 0) == NULL)
            {
              cout << "Error CreateIoCompletionPort" << endl;
              return 2;
            }
            WSAResetEvent(g_ev);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }while(wr != WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0);
}
```

If any body needs more information this links could be useful:
http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedscalableapp6b.html
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SimpleIOCPApp.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302334.aspx

Comment: YOu know what completion ports are?

Comment: Yes, but I have not used AcceptEx and I supposed that this function uses WSAEventSelect to check for incoming connections, of couse the WSAWaitForMultipleEvents must be called on a connection accept thread, maybe this documents would help you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302334.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SimpleIOCPApp.aspx

Comment: Im sorry for being so rude.  I thought, that -when a new connection is made- one event completion packet would be queued to the completion port... but that does not seem to happen. I want the worker threads to handle the new connection socket, not the "parental" function

Comment: Yes the acceptex will be queued to the completion port when the accept happens; assuming you've set it up correctly.

Comment: So I did it wrong... but I don´t want to wait for the AcceptEx to be cmpleted in the AcceptEx-calling thread... that´s what You did in your correction.

Comment: @Incubbus I edited my response, and add a Acceptance Thread.  Maybe you resolved your problem, but I hope this information would be useful for other people with the same problem.

Comment: The example code is, quite simply, NOT how you should use AcceptEx with IOCPs. There's no need to use an event at all, there's no need for any threads apart from the normal IOCP threads (one of the advantages of using AcceptEx over using the traditional accept() loop). You should associate your new socket with the IOCP before you call AcceptEx AND it's essential that you call setsockopt() with SO_UPDATE_ACCEPT_CONTEXT on the accepted socket AFTER the AcceptEx completes...

Answer (score -1):

```
SOCKET newSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

should use `WSASocket` rather than `socket` and you should pass the `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag when creating the socket.

Comment: sockets created with socket() can be used as overalpped ones by default, because they have the overlapped by default (that´s what the msdn says)